# PowerShell - Var inside Format-Volume

Tags: powershell

I'm really new to PowerShell. I'm trying to make a script that detects newly connected USB drives and format them with a new name and NTFS filesystem.

I'm getting an error and the problem seems to be the driveletter name in `Format-Volume`

I used most of the script from the answer here https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device

```
#Requires -version 2.0
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
do{
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
$eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
$eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
{
1 {"Configuration changed"}
2 {"Device arrival"}
3 {"Device removal"}
4 {"docking"}
}
write-host (get-date -format s) " Event detected = " $eventTypeName
if ($eventType -eq 2)
{
$driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
$driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
write-host (get-date -format s) " Drive name = " $driveLetter
write-host (get-date -format s) " Drive label = " $driveLabel
Format-Volume -Driveletter "$driveLetter" -NewFileSystemLabel "test" -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false

[media.SystemSounds]::("Hand").play()
}
Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) #Loop until next event
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

The error I'm getting:

```
2018-10-30T12:45:02  Beginning script...
2018-10-30T12:45:03  Event detected =  Device removal
2018-10-30T12:45:05  Event detected =  Device arrival
2018-10-30T12:45:05  Drive name =  G:
2018-10-30T12:45:05  Drive label =  blabla
Format-Volume : No MSFT_Volume objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to ':'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\formater.ps1:23 char:1
+ Format-Volume -Driveletter "$driveLetter" -NewFileSystemLabel "test"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (::Char) [Format-Volume], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_DriveLetter,Format-Volume
```

I tried with:

```
-Driveletter "$driveLetter"
-Driveletter $driveLetter
-Driveletter ""$driveLetter
```

But with a background in coding for the web, I really don't know how to solve this. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: According to `Get-Help Format-Volume` the DriveLetter parameter expects just a .. DriveLetter no colon. So use `-Driveletter $driveLetter[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`Format-Volume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/format-volume) shows the format that it wants for the `DriveLetter` param as `Char[]`.

So `DriveLetter` should be just the drive letter `G` without the following colon `G:`, you can do this by simply selecting just the first char from `$driveLetter`:

```
-Driveletter $driveLetter[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!... This works, but I´m getting an error when using NTFS. Works fine with other formats like FAT32 or exFAT ...Do you know why?

Comment: Not too sure, I use exFAT as never needed any of the NTFS functionality on a removable drive.